# Simple jquery plugin for converting json to html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I need to append this json data to an html element.

```
[
    {
        "website":"google",
        "link":"http://google.com"
    },
    {
        "website":"facebook",
        "link":"http://fb.com"
    }
]
```

How to convert this easily using any plugin.Presently,I couldn't find any simple plugins in jquery,So please help me friends.

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Why you need plugin to do that... In jquery you can simply append it to html tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi you can use jPut jQuery Plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/jput/)

Create a HTML jPut Template

```
<div jput="template">
  <a href="{{link}}">{{website}}</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var json=[{"website":"google","link":"http://google.com"},
    {"website":"facebook","link":"http://fb.com"}];

   $('#main').jPut({
       jsonData:json,   //your json data
       name:'template'  //jPut template name
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hi thank you very much,Exactly This is what I need to implement.Once again,Thankz a lot,This works for me ...

Answer (score 5):

jPut is easy to use comparing to normal parsing.
if there is lots of data to be appended it is very difficult to append using $.each loop.
in jPut just need to create template & to print the data just put the object name in {{}}.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
data = $.parseJson(json);

$.each(data, function(key, obj) {
    htmlElement = $('<a href="'+link+'">'+website+'</a>');
    $('body').append(htmlElement);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a plugin for this? No need to write a plugin to go around this. Just simply loop it through & do what you wan't with the data. Here is an example:

```
var data = [
    {
        "website":"google",
        "link":"http://google.com"
    },
    {
        "website":"facebook",
        "link":"http://fb.com"
    }
];

var html = '';

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    html += '<a href="' + item.link + '">' + item.website + '</a>';
});

$('body').append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting it to be an anchor tag then -

Html -

```
<div id="siteContainer"></div>
```

JS-

```
var sites = [
    {
        "website":"google",
        "link":"http://google.com"
    },
    {
        "website":"facebook",
        "link":"http://fb.com"
    } 
]

var $container = $('siteContainer');

$(sites).each(function(item, index){
    var name = item['website'];
    var link = item['link'];
    var anchorTag = '<a href="' + link + '">' + name + '</a>');
    $container.appendTo(anchorTag);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

NO need plugin, simply iterate with `each` function and append anchor tag with any `selector` tag.

```
var links = [
    {
        "website":"google",
        "link":"http://google.com"
    },
    {
        "website":"facebook",
        "link":"http://fb.com"
    }
];

$.each(links, function(index, object){
   $("<a></a>").attr("href", object.link).
       text( object.website).css("margin", "5px").appendTo("body");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

no **plugin** needed, can be done without **jquery** too

```
<div id="container">

</div>


<script>

var data = [
    {
        "website":"google",
        "link":"http://google.com"
    },
    {
        "website":"facebook",
        "link":"http://fb.com"
    }
]


document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<a href="'+data[0]['link']+'">'+data[0]['website']+'</a> >> '+data[0]['link']+' <br> <a href="'+data[1]['link']+'">'+data[1]['website']+'</a> >> '+data[1]['link']


</script>
```